# Doctrine very strange behavior: update are not done except if I var_dump

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I encountered a very strange behavior. I have an entity. If I update it in php (not persisted), the entity is not modified in my code, except if I do a var_dump. See my case.
This is my entity.

```
class CommonPeople
{
    /**
     * COLUMN -----------------------------------------------------
     */
    /**
     * @var string
     * @Groups({"id"})
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

/**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getId(): ? string
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
    /**
     * @param string $id
     */
    public function setId(string $id = NULL): void
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }
```

If I do that:

```
$entity = new CommonPeople();
$entity->setId('test.12');
var_dump($entity->getId()); // echo 0
```

but if I add a var_dump in getter:

```
/**
         * @return string
         */
        public function getId(): ? string
        {
            var_dump($this->id);
            return $this->id;
        }
```

I get the expected result:

```
$entity = new CommonPeople();
$entity->setId('test.12');
var_dump($entity->getId()); // echo test.12
```

I don't understand why ? Any idea ?

Comment: If you don't invoke Doctrine, you are working on plain boring PHP so the problem is on your end. My first guess is that maybe `CommonPeople` is actually a proxy object? Check the fully-qualified class name to make sure. Next, throw some dumps into your getter and setters, both before and after retrieval and setting.

Comment: Oh thanks, you're right, I used DoctrineProxy !